# .NET Remoting threading

Tags: .net, .net-remoting

I have a class which inherits from MarshalByRef on which I make several calls. What I require is some sort of thread affinity for all calls to the object. That is to say every method which I call from my client is marshalled to the same thread on the "server" side. Does anyone know how or indeed if I could achieve this using .NET remoting, or would a more custom approach be required.

Comment: Does the server have a [`SynchronizationContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx) you could capture? Does the thread need to be a thread with a message pump (the UI thread) or does it just matter that it is the same thread ID for every call?

Comment: I can inherit from ContextBoundObject and then add the attribute [Synchronization(true)], I suppose this enables be to capture the context somehow? No it doesn't need to be a UI thread just a thread with the same thread ID for every call.

Comment: This is not generally possible, you cannot force a thread to execute an arbitrary method.  The thread has to co-operate, it needs to solve the universal [producer-consumer problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem).  It must announce that is ready to execute code, take a request and execute it.  The UI thread of an app always solves that problem, also provides a SynchronizationContext implementation, you'll have to solve it yourself.  A thread-safe queue and a loop in the thread that empties it is what it takes.